# Given the joint p.d.f., are $X$ and $Y$ independent? What is the conditional p.d.f. of $X$ given $Y=y$

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, independence, density-function

Let $(X,Y)$ be two random variables with joint p.d.f.
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{y}e^{-x/y}e^{-y}&\text{if }0<x<\infty\text{ and }0<y<\infty\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

1. What is the marginal of $Y$?
2. Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?
3. What is the conditional p.d.f. of $X$ given $Y=y$?
4. What is $\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y]$?

**My Attempt**

1. The marginal of $Y$ can be found by integrating the joint p.d.f. w.r.t. $x$. So
   $$f_Y(y)=\int^\infty_0f_{X,Y}(x,y)dx=\int^\infty_0\frac{1}{y}e^{-x/y}e^{-y}dx=\left[-e^{-x/y-y}\right]^\infty_0=e^{-y}$$
2. To know if they are independent, we must check that $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$. This means we need to find the marginal p.d.f. for $X$. My problem is that the integral is quite hard, and even after using an online integral calculator, I was given a gamma function that could not be computed for the bounds $[0,\infty)$. Since this is not a calculus class, I was wondering if there is some easier way to check independence that I am missing.
3. I know the formula for the conditional p.d.f. of $X$ given $Y$:
   $$f_{X|Y}=\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}=\frac{\frac{1}{y}e^{-x/y}e^{-y}}{e^{-y}}=\frac{1}{y}e^{-x/y}$$
   My concern is that I was asked for the conditional p.d.f. of $X$ given $Y=y$. Is there a difference between the two or is it just different ways of writing it?
4. $$\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y]=\int^\infty_0xf_{X|Y}(x\mid y)dx$$
   Using the last part, we have
   $$=\int^\infty_0\frac{x}{y}e^{-x/y}dx=\left[-(x+y)e^{-x/y}\right]^\infty_0=y$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 2. if $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $f_X(x)=\frac{f_{XY}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$ should not depend on $y$, which is clearly not the case for your pdf. There is no need to explicitly calculate $f_X(x)$

For 3. instead of $f_{X|Y}$ you should write $f_{X|Y}(x|y)=\ldots$

Answer (score 0):

The joint density factors as

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\underbrace{\frac1ye^{-x/y}\mathbf1_{(0,\infty)}(x)}_{f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)}\cdot \underbrace{e^{-y}\mathbf1_{(0,\infty)}(y)}_{f_Y(y)} \tag{$\star$}$$

From the conditional density $f_{X\mid Y}(\cdot\mid y)$, it is clear that the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y=y\,(>0)$ depends on $y$. Hence $X$ and $Y$ cannot be independent.

In fact writing the joint pdf in the form of $(\star)$ answers all four questions immediately.

The distribution of $X$ given $Y=y$ is clearly Exponential with mean $y$.

Since $\mathbb E\left[X\mid Y=y\right]=y$ for all $y>0$, one should write $$\mathbb E\left[X\mid Y\right]=Y\quad,\,\text{a.e.}$$